# get specific parent in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, parent, parents

I have the following HTML and I need to get the first div parent of the object (collapse)

If this parent has a class of (ZeroClass) .. I want to have the next div parent ..

```
<div>
  <div id = "DeadCode">
    <div class = "ZeroClass">
      <table class = "zeroTable">
         <...tableData...>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the jQuery Function :

```
function ResizeGrid(){
    var collapse = $(".zeroTable").parent();

    if ($(collapse).hasClass("ZeroClass")) {
        collapse = $(collapse).parents($("div"));
    }
}
```

Everything goes fine but when passing through the if statement, it makes Collapse Null .. any ideas?

Comment: can you tell where is `.rgMasterTable` class in your html.

Comment: parent().parent().parents($("div")); ? Seriously ? Not heard of closest() ?

Comment: don't use camel case in CSS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437527/css-camelcase-vs-under-score

Comment: sorry guys I wrote it wrong at first.. now it's edited .. 
I don't want the closest .. I want a specific parent with a specific class .. the problem is with the line 
collapse = collapse.parents($("div")) .. it always returns null ..

Comment: works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/PTWEV/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `parent` for the first step and [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) for the second:

```
function ResizeGrid() {
    var $collapse = $(".zeroTable").parent();

    if ($collapse.hasClass("ZeroClass")) {
        $collapse = $collapse.closest("div");
    }
}
```

Your problem lies in this row:

```
collapse = $(collapse).parents($("div"));
```

You first fetch ALL div elements `$("div")` and then tell `$(collapse).parents()` to match one of them.

My code:

```
$collapse = $collapse.closest("div");
```

Tells jQuery to find the closest parent div.

It's a good practice to prefix jQuery variables with `$` to help keep track of which vars are jQuery objects and which are regular DOM nodes.

Comment: You just did something like this: `$($(...))` read your code again... :) **HINT:** `collapse` is already a jQuery object...

Comment: @gdoron: Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: Thanks jgauffin, but this didn't work, cuz the closest() checks the element itself first .. unfortunately :(

Comment: since the .closest()  checks the element first, I used .parent().closest and it worked fine .. thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Just worked on your HTML and script you have given and found following thing with it Check the below demo

http://jsfiddle.net/ffRN7/37/

Demo1 will addClass to closest div

Modified line for finding the closest div in below script...

```
$(collapse).closest("div").addClass("divclass");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ffRN7/38/

Demo2 will add class to the parents div which do not have any id or class 
Script in case fiddle is not accessible:

```
function ResizeGrid(){

        var collapse = $(".zeroTable").parent();

    if ($(collapse).hasClass("ZeroClass")){
            $(collapse).parents("div").addClass("divclass");

        }
    }

        $("a").bind("click", ResizeGrid);
```

CSS

```
.zeroTable td {border:1px solid black}
.ZeroClass {border:1px solid green; width:90%; height:50px; margin:5px;}

#DeadCode {border:1px solid blue; width:95%; height:100px; }

.divclass{height:200px; padding:5px; background-color:yellow;}
```